Why do the points of my triangle bend inwards?
I'm trying to make a tiny software renderer in hopes I can make some crappy little game in the far future, and I've hit a roadblock where nothing helps at all. I've found that whenever I go into the wall I've setup, that it bends inwards which is noticeable when I'm going into it at an angle, and nothing online has helped so far. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.
What I do is first get the coordinates of a segment in my level (XY), and convert that into "World" coordinates which is literally just transforming the coordinates with cosine and sine. Afterwards, when I want to be able to use these coordinates to render a triangle on screen, I use the WorldToScreen function in my code, which applies the projection stuff (like x/y or z/y) and multiplies that by focal length and adds the proper screen offset for the outputted x, y coordinates.
For the wall as seen in the pictures, it starts off as a straight line, but is given height based off of a constant value for now. From there, I can draw the triangles.
Since later today, after I posted this question, I figured out the problem lies within the projection system.
Here is a video showing an example of the problem.


Apologies if my code is messy. Some of the stuff could be better, but I'm just trying to fix the problem I have at the moment. Any help is appreciated
import pygame, math
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np

screenArray = None
W, H = None, None
WALL_RANGE = 5000 # Walls can only be 5000 px in length on screen.

@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def fill_triangle(screenArray, a, b, c, col, checkIfFreePixel):
    # Calculate the bounding box of the triangle
    xmin = int(max(0, min(a[0], b[0], c[0])))
    ymin = int(max(0, min(a[1], b[1], c[1])))
    xmax = int(min(screenArray.shape[0] - 1, max(a[0], b[0], c[0])))
    ymax = int(min(screenArray.shape[1] - 1, max(a[1], b[1], c[1])))

    def get_determinant(a, b, c):
        ab = (a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1])
        ac = (c[0] - a[0], c[1] - a[1])
        return ab[1] * ac[0] - ab[0] * ac[1]

    # Iterate over the bounding box of the triangle
    for y in prange(ymin, ymax + 1):
        for x in prange(xmin, xmax + 1):
            p = (x, y)
            w0 = get_determinant(b, c, p)
            w1 = get_determinant(c, a, p)
            w2 = get_determinant(a, b, p)

            # Check if the point is inside the triangle
            if (w0 >= 0 and w1 >= 0 and w2 >= 0) or (w0 <= 0 and w1 <= 0 and w2 <= 0):
                if (x > 1 and x < W-1) and (y > 1 and y < H-1):
                    if not checkIfFreePixel:
                        screenArray[x, y] = col
                    else:  # Used for floors and ceilings
                        if screenArray[x, y][0] + screenArray[x, y][1] + screenArray[x, y][2] > 0:
                            continue
                        else:
                            screenArray[x, y] = col

class Engine:
    def __init__(self, w, h, FOV, FocalLength, screen):
        global screenArray
        global W
        global H
        self.w=w
        self.h=h
        self.w2=w/2
        self.h=h
        self.h2=h/2
        self.FOV=FOV
        self.FocalLength=FocalLength
        self.sin = [0]*360
        self.cos = [0]*360
        #self.screenArray = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.surface.Surface((w,h)))
        self.blankArray = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.surface.Surface((w,h)))
        screenArray = self.blankArray.copy()
        W=w
        H=h
        self.screen = screen

        for x in range(360):
            self.sin[x] = math.sin(x/180*math.pi)
            self.cos[x] = math.cos(x/180*math.pi)
    def screenClip(self, value):
        return int(max(min(value[0], self.w-1), 0)), int(max(min(value[1], self.h-1), 0))
    def XYToWorld(self, a, cs, sn):
        x = a[0]*cs-a[1]*sn
        y = a[1]*cs+a[0]*sn
        return (x, y)
    def WorldToScreen(self, a):
        x = a[0]
        y = 1+abs(a[1])
        z = a[2]

        x = (x/y)*self.FocalLength+self.w2
        y = (z/y)*self.FocalLength+self.h2
        return (x, y)

    def projectWall(self, wall, character):
        wallBottom = 0
        wallTop = 2
        wallHeight = wallTop-wallBottom
        yaw = np.radians(character.yaw)
        sn = np.sin(yaw)
        cs = np.cos(yaw)
        cx = character.x
        cy = character.y
        x1, x2 = wall[0]-cx, wall[2]-cx
        y1, y2 = wall[1]-cy, wall[3]-cy
        wz0 = wallBottom-character.z
        wz1 = wallBottom-character.z
        wz2 = wz0+wallHeight
        wz3 = wz1+wallHeight

        wx0, wy0 = self.XYToWorld((x1, y1), cs, sn)
        wx1, wy1 = self.XYToWorld((x2, y2), cs, sn)
        
        wx2, wx3 = wx0, wx1
        wy2, wy3 = wy0, wy1

        wallLength = math.hypot(wall[0], wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
        if wy0 < 1 and wy1 < 1:
            return None
        # Calculate the depth (average Z value)
        depth = (wy0+wy1)/2
        wx0, wy0 = self.WorldToScreen((wx0, wy0, wz0))
        wx1, wy1 = self.WorldToScreen((wx1, wy1, wz1))
        wx2, wy2 = self.WorldToScreen((wx2, wy2, wz2))
        wx3, wy3 = self.WorldToScreen((wx3, wy3, wz3))
        wx0, wy0 = (int(wx0), int(wy0))
        wx1, wy1 = (int(wx1), int(wy1))
        wx2, wy2 = (int(wx2), int(wy2))
        wx3, wy3 = (int(wx3), int(wy3))
        return depth, ((wx0, wy0),(wx1, wy1),(wx2,wy2),(wx3,wy3))
    def update(self, sectors, character):
        player_position = (character.x, character.y)
        ## find and set depth of sectors, then sort by furthest distance first
        for sector in sectors:
            x = sector[0]-character.x
            y = sector[1]-character.y
            sector[2] = math.hypot(x, y)
        sectors.sort(key=lambda item: item[2], reverse=True)

        for sector in sectors: # start drawing sectors
            wallData = []
            walls = sector[3]
            # Collect depth and coordinates for each wall
            for wall in walls:
                result = self.projectWall(wall, character)
                if result is not None:
                    depth, coords = result
                    wallData.append((depth, coords, wall[4]))  # Store depth, coordinates, and color
            wallData.sort(key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)
            for depth, coords, color in wallData:
                (wx0, wy0), (wx1, wy1), (wx2, wy2), (wx3, wy3) = coords
                a, b, c, d = (wx0, wy0), (wx1, wy1), (wx2, wy2), (wx3, wy3)
                fill_triangle(screenArray, a,b,c, color, False)
                fill_triangle(screenArray, d,c,b, color, False)
    def draw(self):
        global screenArray
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(self.screen, screenArray)
        screenArray = self.blankArray.copy()
    ```


A video might help. It's difficult to get a sense of what's happening between these two stills, for a reader who's never seen your app before.

It might also help to edit your question to add an explanation for the strategy / algorithm you're using to draw this wall, or code comments explaining your thinking step by step. I'm finding it a little difficult to understand what you're trying to do in places - like why does the character's yaw contribute to the calculation of a wall's world coordinates? Unless by "world" you really mean "view" (a coordinate system relative to the camera's position and facing direction)?

^ I did that, apologies that I never included those and had to take a century to reply. By character yaw, it'd just be the cameras orientation. You can only turn left and right, as I'm just going for something really small here and nothing special. I hope my explanation will suffice.
New to the platform, and I've practically had my brain turn to mush, so that should partially explain why I forgot some key information before.

It looks like you might be missing clipping, so vertices that slip close to / behind the image plane are projected incorrectly and distort the parts of the shape connected to them. Does that sound like it might be related?

I tried clipping lines before, but that never seemed to work, most likely because I didn't do it correctly. Also, clipping came to mind first thing when I encountered this problem for the first time. I'll see what I can do, thank you :)
